# Does the 'MSDeployUseChecksum' option work with the FileSystem Publish method

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines, webdeploy

I am trying to implement a deployment step using MSBuild with options `DeployOnBuild` and a PublishProfile with the `WebPublishMethod` set to `FileSystem`.

My PublishProfile looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <MSDeployUseChecksum>true</MSDeployUseChecksum>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I am calling this from a build script that invokes MSBuild on individual projects and sets the PublishUrl depending on the build target (developer or deployment):

```
>msbuild.exe /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=c:\path\to\Profile.pubxml /p:SolutionDir=c:\path\to\solution /p:PublishUrl=c:\path\to\target /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 c:\path\to\project.csproj
```

The build process is intended to overlay project resources, including DLLs, over a third-party application. Due to behavior of NuGet restore, later versions of DLLs do not consistently have later change dates, so are being skipped during the deployment process. I have added the MSDeployUseChecksum option, which per documentation ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/29/web-publishing-updates-for-app-offline-and-usechecksum/)) should resolve the issue, but is not having an impact.

Does MSDeployUseChecksum work with the FileSystem deployment method? If yes, are any additional steps or settings required to make it work?

Comment: Any update on this? I have the same problem but I'm using Package as web publish method.Some nuget files even they have higher versions won't be updated but second time will be fine.